# Jackson: pass a backreference parameter to a @JsonCreator factory method

Tags: json, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a bi-directional one-to-many relationship between two classes I'm trying to deserialize from JSON. Because the mapping between the JSON and the class properties is not direct I'd like to use a factory method annotated with `@JsonCreator` but it seems like there's no way to pass the back-reference object when I'm creating the objects at the *many* end of the relationship. The `@JsonBackReference` annotation cannot be applied to a parameter and is ignored if I add it to a field. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is bit of a chicken-and-egg problem here, so it is probably not doable as creator property.

But it should definitely work with fields or setters (you can make setter private; Jackson has no problem accessing it, as long as it is properly marked as back-reference property).